# How to check if directory is not containing hidden dir and one specific dir

Tags: scripts

I'd like to see if "/tmp" dir contains hidden dir and dir named "test"

Currently ls -la /tmp contains below

```
.
..
test
```

I'd like to check if /tmp doesn't contain anything else besides above using shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this command to list any hidden directories and avoid listing "." which refers to directory itself.

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname ".*" -a -not -name "."
```

Output of this command can either piped to `grep` or used in a variable and tested with  `[ -z "$VAR" ]` to check if the string is empty. If it is, there's no hidden directories